# How to make a clone of a selected element in dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to select an element from the drop down list and make a copy of it and add it in the same drop down menu.

I found many answers in which the whole list is cloned instead of the selected element. like

```
function CopyItem1()
   {
        $('#list1').append($('#list1').html());
   }
```

Comment: Maybe you should Google 'jQuery clone'?

Comment: Look at [Node.cloneNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.cloneNode) -- `var list1 = document.getElementById("list1"), list1SelectedNodeClone = list1.options[list1.selectedIndex].cloneNode(/* true */);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
$('#list1').append(function(){
   return $(this).find(':selected').clone(); //return the clone of selected option to be appended.
});
```

Comment: Thank you PSL.Can you please tell me how to add distinct values to the dropdown menu as well.


    function AddItem1(text,value)

        {
          var select = document.getElementById('list1');
        select.options[select.options.length] = new Option('CD2', 'CD2');
           
        }

By this I am adding CD2 again and again.
How can I add Cd2, Cd3, Cd4 by clicking on add. 

Please help thanks :)

Comment: @user3154712 Yes you can, can you paste your minimal code in a jsbin and share http://jsbin.com/. btw are you using jquery?

Comment: I am trying to add/delete/copy different values in dropdown by clicking on a button.

Comment: Now copy is working fine. and when I am adding it only adds cd2 again and again. how can I make a for loop to add values till cd2 to cd10. I am new to js.

Comment: @user3154712 Can you paste your html as well in the appropriate panel in the jsbin. What do yo want to change the value of the cloned element? Use this http://jsbin.com/icalokI/1/

Comment: http://jsbin.com/EqUlUyi/1/

I am making a dropdown menu in which a user can add new values and delete/copy the existing values and you can see the results in the dropdown menu.

Comment: @user3154712 If i understand correctly you could do `function AddItem(text,value)
    {
     
      var select = $('#list');
      var option = $('<option />',{'text':'Toogle_Image_Recipe_' + (select.children().length + 1)});
      select.append(option);
    
}`  http://jsbin.com/aduYiwE/1/

Comment: Thank you sooo much. One last request Can you please help in deleting a particluar item too. In my case it is deleting one first one in the list.

Comment: @peter please tell me this.